# Exporting Data to CSV in R

Tags: r, csv

I have merged a bunch of csv files but cant get them to export to one file correctly what am i doing wrong?The data shows up in my console but I get a error that says "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.fram",

```
setwd("c:/users/adam/documents/r data/NBA/DK/TEMP")
filenames <- list.files("c:/users/adam/documents/r data/NBA/DK/TEMP")
do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))

write.csv(read.csv, file ='Lineups.csv')
```

Comment: have you confirmed the files _read_ correctly? it seems not. use `fwrite` for file export btw

Comment: OK. I initially thought the lack of assignment was the source of the error until I saw what at the time was a trailing bit of code. Edited Q and added the extra text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not assign the results of do.call function to anything. Fairly common R noob error. Failure to understand the functional programming paradigm. Results need to be assigned to R names or they just get garbage-collected.

The error is actually from the code that you didn't put in a code block:

```
write.csv(read.csv, file ='Lineups.csv')
```

The 'read.csv' was presumably your intended name for the result of the `do.call`-operation, except it is by default a function name rather than your expectation. You could assign the `do.call`-results to the name 'read.csv' but doing so is very poor practice. Choose a more descriptive name like 'TEMP_files_appended'.

```
TEMP_files_appended <- do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))

write.csv(TEMP_files_appended, file ='Lineups.csv')
```

(I will observe that using `header=TRUE` for `read.csv` is not needed since that is the default for that function.)

Comment: Can you tell me the CSV files im joining are named MB1,MB2,MB3 all the way up to MB455.  When it joins them it joins MB1,MB10,MB100,MB101 etc... How do I get it to join them by going MB1,MB2,MB3...etc?

Comment: `for (names in paste0("M", 1:455)) {do stuff}` or perhaps `do.call(rbind, mget( paste0("M", 1:455) ) )`