# how to create csv for my output in R programming

Tags: r

```
library(pdftools)
library(data.table)
library(tabulizer)
pdf_file <- "new.pdf"

out2 <- extract_tables(pdf_file, pages = 89, output = "data.frame")
out2
```

**output*:*

[image]

Can someone help me how to change the output(out2) into CSV/Dataframe using R programing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting Data to CSV in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046013/exporting-data-to-csv-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the file, run:

```
write.csv(out2,'out2.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
write.csv(data.df,"address that you want to create in", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Welcome. Whilst this may answer the question, good answers should include some commentary to help other users understand what the code does. Thank you.